# AdvertisingIdClient getAdvertisingIdInfo blocked by main thread

Tags: java, android, multithreading, google-play-services

I'm trying to wait the response of AdvertisingIdClient.getAdvertisingIdInfo(activity) without success. This method never response until the main thread has finished.

```java
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.SystemClock;
import android.util.Log;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.identifier.AdvertisingIdClient;
import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil;
import java.io.IOException;


public class MyActivity extends Activity {

    private Activity m_activity = null;
    private AdvertisingIdClient.Info m_info = null;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        // start the thread with the getAdvertisingIdInfo()
        startGoogleAdvertisingIdRequest(this);

        // simulate a waiting loop, others app init, ...
        for (int i=0; i<20; i++) {
            SystemClock.sleep(100);
        }

        // get the uuid
        String uuid = getGoogleAdvertisingId();

        // call a method who need the uuid
        Log.i("UUID", "receive uuid: " + uuid);
    }


    public String getGoogleAdvertisingId() {
        String uuid = null;
        if (m_info != null) {
            if (!m_info.isLimitAdTrackingEnabled()) {
                uuid = m_info.getId();
            } else {
                uuid = "another uuid";
            }
        } else {
            uuid = "another uuid";
        }

        return uuid;
    }

    public void startGoogleAdvertisingIdRequest(final Activity activity) {
        m_activity = activity;
        if (GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(activity) == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    AdvertisingIdClient.Info adInfo = null;
                    try {
                        Log.i("UUID", "before google request");
                        adInfo = AdvertisingIdClient.getAdvertisingIdInfo(activity);
                        Log.i("UUID", "after google request");
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        Log.w("UUID", "getAdvertisingIdInfo IOException: " + e.getMessage());
                    } catch (GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException e) {
                        Log.w("UUID", "GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException: " + e.getMessage());
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        Log.w("UUID", "GooglePlayServicesException: " + e.getMessage());
                    } finally {
                        finished(adInfo);
                    }
                }
            }).start();
        }
    }

    private void finished(final AdvertisingIdClient.Info adInfo){
        if(adInfo != null){
            m_activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    m_info = adInfo;
                    Log.i("UUID", "runOnUiThread id: " + adInfo.getId());
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Logcat of this code

```bash
11:29:52.103  30810-30828/com.example.testuuid I/UUID﹕ before google request
11:29:54.107  30810-30810/com.example.testuuid I/UUID﹕ receive uuid: another uuid
11:29:54.127  30810-30828/com.example.testuuid I/UUID﹕ after google request
11:29:54.151  30810-30810/com.example.testuuid I/UUID﹕ runOnUiThread id: d5dc3bfb-4756-490c-8f8e-2bedfb5e827a
```

Same logcat with more waiting time (5s)

```bash
11:36:14.215  31413-31436/com.example.testuuid I/UUID﹕ before google request
11:36:19.225  31413-31413/com.example.testuuid I/UUID﹕ receive uuid: another uuid
11:36:19.293  31413-31436/com.example.testuuid I/UUID﹕ after google request
11:36:19.315  31413-31413/com.example.testuuid I/UUID﹕ runOnUiThread id: d5dc3bfb-4756-490c-8f8e-2bedfb5e827a
```

Each time the getAdvertisingIdInfo(), who is in another thread, is blocked by the main thread.

What is the reason ? and how to do this ?

Comment: Have you considered using [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)?

Comment: @Fildor: Yes, I try AsyncTask, the problem is the same.

Comment: Then my guess is that `m_info.getId();` is blocking.

Comment: m_info.getId() is not called here (fallback to "another uuid" because m_info is null because the response comes too late).

Comment: Have you tried putting the call to isGooglePlayServicesAvailable into the thread?

Comment: I have tried, it change nothing. If you look at the logs, the thread start and works well until the getAdvertisingIdInfo() begin, and then block until the onCreate is complety done.

Comment: You give the activity which has not finished onCreate to getAdvertisingUdInfo inside thread. I guess it waits for the activity to finish onCreate. Try fetching the id in some later lifecycle callback. Or lazy in the first place.

Comment: It seemed a good point. I move all in onStart(), but the problem is still present.

Comment: Just noting that this issue is still out there.  I am having the same problem.  For all the answers below, the request is definitely on a background thread.  Note the problem is NOT that the request BLOCKS the main thread but that it is BLOCKED BY the main thread.   Some internal bit of code is somehow waiting on main before proceeding.   Still looking for a solution.  Feels like a Play SDK bug.

Comment: Can you please share the sample project in Github?

Answer (score 7):

To get the google ad ID you need not to run the method `getAdvertisingIdInfo` on the main thread.
I use Async Task to manage the extraction of the google ad ID.

```
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.identifier.AdvertisingIdClient;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesRepairableException;
import java.io.IOException;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
String GAID; // this is the String of the Google Ad ID that you'll receive upon onPostExecute

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    new GetGAIDTask().execute();
}

private class GetGAIDTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
        AdvertisingIdClient.Info adInfo;
        adInfo = null;
            try {
                adInfo = AdvertisingIdClient.getAdvertisingIdInfo(MainActivity.this.getApplicationContext());
                if (adInfo.isLimitAdTrackingEnabled()) // check if user has opted out of tracking
                    return "did not found GAID... sorry";
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (GooglePlayServicesRepairableException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        return adInfo.getId();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        GAID = s;
    }
}
```

You also need to add to the app build.gradle on the dependencies the line

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:7.8.0'
```

And be sure you have on the Android SDK manager the "EXTRAS Google Repository" updated

Answer (score 1):

In the literature about AdvertisingIdClient it says to not use on main thread.  It will throw an exception. So if you put it into it's own thread you will be fine, most likely.

[AdvertisingIdClient reference](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/ads/identifier/AdvertisingIdClient.html#getAdvertisingIdInfo(android.content.Context))

Answer (score 1):

The issue you are seeing, where no amount of time seems long enough for the getAdvertisingIdInfo call to complete, is caused by how you are waiting and how runOnUiThread works. The key is that runOnUiThread will queue the code to be run after what is currently running on the ui thread, in this case the onCreate. The sleep calls used to "simulate waiting" will let your background thread run and do its work, but the final operation to set m_info will always be queued and executed after onCreate completes.

One solution would be to ensure that m_info is safe to access from multiple threads and simply assign it on the background thread. There would be no need for runOnUiThread. This would remove queuing, and allow your code to work with minimal changes.

A better solution would be to keep the use of runOnUiThread and remove the sleep used to wait. You would need to keep in mind that m_info will always be null in onCreate, but other events can check if the value is non null and use it as needed.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#runOnUiThread(java.lang.Runnable)

> Runs the specified action on the UI thread. If the current thread is the UI thread, then the action is executed immediately. If the current thread is not the UI thread, the action is posted to the event queue of the UI thread.

Answer (score 0):

According to the docs ([**here**](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/ads/identifier/AdvertisingIdClient)) :

> Unfortunately, in these cases using the com.google.android.gms.iid
> InstanceID API or system functions to create an app-scoped ID are not
> appropriate solutions because the ID may need to be shared across
> apps. An alternative solution is to use the Advertising Identifier
> available from the AdvertisingIdClient.Info class via the getId()
> method. You can create an AdvertisingIdClient.Info object using the
> getAdvertisingIdInfo(Context) method and call the getId() method to
> use the identifier. Note that this method is blocking, so you should
> not call it from the main thread; a detailed explanation of this
> method is available here.

Also [**here**](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/ads/identifier/AdvertisingIdClient.html#getAdvertisingIdInfo(android.content.Context)):

> public static AdvertisingIdClient.Info getAdvertisingIdInfo (Context
> context)
>
> Retrieves the user's advertising ID and limit ad tracking preference.
>
> This method cannot be called in the main thread as it may block
> leading to ANRs. An IllegalStateException will be thrown if this is
> called on the main thread.

So they say it's blocking...
You need to put this code in a background thread.