# AdvertisingIdClient#getAdvertisingIdInfo sometimes returns null since v9.8.0

Tags: android, google-play-services

I got an issue since I bumped the play-services version to v9.8.0. I notice that the method AdvertisingIdClient#getAdvertisingIdInfo sometimes returns null (i have not identified any pattern to reproduce this case yet).

Do you if this a new behavior of this API (The documentation is not clear whether this method may return null or not) or if this a bug i should report to play services developers ?

This is a breaking change for me because I use some sdk which use this method without checking the returned value nullity.

Thanks !

Comment: I'm not sure if this is a bug in Google Play Service v9.8 or not. But from the meantime, check this [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27961634/advertisingidclient-getadvertisingidinfo-blocked-by-main-thread) if it can help you on how to implement AdvertisingIdClient. Also, did you receive any kind of error message? And if you decide to report this to play services developers, can you update us the community about this issue. Thanks.

Comment: Seeing this too, on a Kindle Fire device (no GAID). Definitely a bug, docs are clear about the possible returned values, seem to be broken since 9.8.0 and through to 10.0.1 . Posted here https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/play/sg8c6ekj6aQ , hopefully it will reach the devs.

Answer (score 0):

I'm seeing this too, but can't find any useful links about it. If you use Android Studio to decompile the `getAdvertisingIdInfo` method you can clearly see a path where it will return `null` but [the docs](http://www.androiddocs.com/google/play-services/id.html) don't see to think that is possible. I can't find anywhere to report a bug, it's probably safest to just update your code to check for `null`.

Comment: It probably is safest but the op uses third-party SDK, and so do I.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is probably that you use the old dependency:

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/216160966

You need to use the new one:

```
implementation("com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-identifier:18.0.1")
```

- https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup#list-dependencies
- https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/ads/identifier/AdvertisingIdClient

Example usage:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        thread {
            val advertisingId = getAdvertisingId(this)
            Log.d("AppLog", "result:$advertisingId")
        }
    }

    @WorkerThread
    fun getAdvertisingId(context: Context): String? {
        return try {
            val idInfo = AdvertisingIdClient.getAdvertisingIdInfo(context)
            val isLimitAdTrackingEnabled = idInfo.isLimitAdTrackingEnabled
            Log.d("AppLog", "isLimitAdTrackingEnabled?$isLimitAdTrackingEnabled")
            idInfo.id
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            Log.d("AppLog", "error:$e")
            e.printStackTrace()
            // Unrecoverable error connecting to Google Play services (e.g. the old version of the service doesn't support getting AdvertisingId).
            null
        }
    }
}
```